# I have added FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag, but I still get "outside of an Activity context requires" error

Tags: android

I still get the error "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag" when I invoke `PublicParFun.ShareAPP(getApplicationContext());` I have added FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

BTW, PublicParFun.ShowMainUI(getApplicationContext()) can work well, why?

**CallerMin.java**

```
package ui;

import info.dodata.callernametalker.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import bll.PublicParFun;

public class CallerMain extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.caller_main);       
        SetButtons();       
    }

    private void SetButtons() {
        findViewById(R.id.btnSettings).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PublicParFun.ShowMainUI(getApplicationContext());
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btnShare).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PublicParFun.ShareAPP(getApplicationContext());
            }
        });     

        findViewById(R.id.btnClose).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                finish();
            }
        });     
    }


}
```

**PublicParFun.java**

```
package bll;

public class PublicParFun {

    public static void ShowMainUI(Context myContext){
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(myContext,ui.CallerMain.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS); 
        myContext.startActivity(intent);
    }


    public static void ShareAPP(Context myContext){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS); 

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, myContext.getString(R.string.ShareTitle));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, myContext.getString(R.string.ShareTitle));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myContext.getString(R.string.ShareContent));

        try {
            myContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    myContext.getString(R.string.defautlClient)));

        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(myContext,
                    myContext.getString(R.string.defautlNoClient), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }   
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CallerMain activity class

instead of getApplicationContext() inside

```
PublicParFun.ShowMainUI(getApplicationContext());
```

do CallerMain.this as

```
PublicParFun.ShowMainUI(CallerMain.this);
```

Comment: To Rajen Raiyarela: Thanks! Your code works, could you tell me why?

Comment: Frankly speaking i do not have any technical explanation for this. I too faced this issue in one of my application and doing this solved it. At that time i almost spent a week searching for this after i solved to understand why activityname.this worked and getApplicationContext() did not, but did not find any explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

try add the FLAG on Manisfest.

Comment: This does not solve the problem.  This rather nonsense actually.